# Salesforce Lightning Process Builder

Tags: workflow, visual-flows, process-builder, pilot

I am testing out the new Process Builder in Salesforce (Pilot). Working on a MacBook Pro I am having problems with the "Define criteria for this Action Group" pane, it is not able to fully display everything needed, for example, when trying to select the field for the filter logic, I am unable to select the the fields form the list displayed. Is this a rendering issue with OS X/Safari or does it happen across all browsers?

Answer (score 4):

the new Process Builder (beta) version only supports the latest version of the Google Chrome browser. Please try Chrome and if it's a rendering issue that should get resolved. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Shelly, is there a timeline for support on other browsers?

Comment: We will be supporting other browsers in the coming releases. Thx